# How to read a file in Perl till it matches certain string/value

Tags: perl

I have one text file which has entries like

```
123
123
234
456
789
654
123
123
123
```

I am trying to write a perl script which opens and reads through the file (while doing so, it has to ignore second 123 and read through till next 123 is repeated):

Desired output:

```
123 # Keep
123 # Ignore
234 # Keep
456 # Keep
789 # Keep
654 # Keep
123 # Keep and stop here
```

Comment: What is expected output? Are you trying to ignore duplicates?

Comment: Expected output should be 123 234 456 789 654 123

Comment: @ds_p - your question doesn't really make any sense. You should think clearly about what exactly you're trying to achieve and re-word your question. You also need to provide some code that you've written in an attempt to solve this yourself

Comment: @fugu, my apologies for not being able to post the question clearly. I am very new to this group and this is the first question I have posted. Also  I am new to perl and started learning only from couple of days. Your code is absolutely working perfect. Thanks a lot. From now on I will try to follow the guidelines properly. Thanks again

Comment: @ds_p: If _fugu_'s code is working for you, then you must accept that as an answer, so it can be close as solved.

Comment: @serenesat  fugu's code is working fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# open my $file, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!; # If you're reading in from a file use this

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $seen{$_}++;    
    next if $seen{$_} == 2;
    print "$_\n";
    last if $seen{$_} > 2;
}


__DATA__
123
123
234
456
789
654
123
123
123
```

---output---

```
123
234
456
789
654
123
```

Comment: this code gives me blank output.Please let me know if I need to add any thing extra for this to work. Thanks a lot for the answer though.